# Automate the Boring Stuff: Phone number and email extractor

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I tried to modify the code to extract Indian phone numbers, but the output seems to print each phone number twice. The email part works fine but I don't get the desired out put when printing the phone nubers

```
    #! python3
    # PhoneandEmail.py - Finds all the phone numbers and emails in the clipboard

    import pyperclip, re

    phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
        (\+)?   
        (\s)?
        (91)?
        (\s)?
        (\d{5})
        (\s)?
        (\d{5})
        )''', re.VERBOSE)

    emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
        [a-zA-Z0-9_%+-]+ # username
        @                # @ symbol
        [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+   # domain name
        (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})# dot-something
        )''', re.VERBOSE)


    text = str(pyperclip.paste())
    matches = []
    for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
        phoneNum = ''.join(groups)
        matches.append(phoneNum)

    for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
        matches.append(groups[0])

    if len(matches) > 0 :
        pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
        print('coppied to clipboard')
        print('\n'.join(matches))
    else: 
        print('nothing found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
        (\+)?   
        (\s)?
        (91)?
        (\s)?
        (\d{5})
        (\s)?
        (\d{5})
        )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

You are finding the capture groups and joining them in phoneNum
now the capture groups `(\+)`,`(\s)`,`(91)`,`(\s)`,`(\d{5})`,`(\s)`, and `(\d{5})` together make up a phone number.
and the large capture group `( (\+)?    (\s)? (91)? (\s)? (\d{5}) (\s)? (\d{5}) )`
also captures the phone number. Hence a phone number is printed twice.

Comment: Thank you , but how do I solve this?

Comment: remove the outer capture group. `phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(\+)?(\s)?(91)?(\s)?(\d{5}) (\s)?(\d{5})''',re.VERBOSE)`

Comment: Another way: You can also make the inner groups non capturing: `phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''((?:\+)?(?:\s)?(?:91)?(?:\s)?(?:\d{5})(?:\s)?(?:\d{5}))''',re.VERBOSE)` . You make a group non capturing using `(?:)`.